# creating an interactive page (videos, photos) for sharing on iOS device

Tags: ios, xcode

I am building an iOS app, using storyboard. I have created a page where the user can create a page that will then be then published on DropBox and shared between all app users. this page lets you add photos, videos (not yet), and textviews (with scrolling enabled). Until know when the user presses the upload button, a screenshot is taken and uploaded, then views from a table view. but obviously it is just an image, so you can't scroll the textfields to see all the content and if I wanted to add the video support it would not be able to play it. I tried doing research on the internet, but I am a bit confused. Do I have to save all the components (UITextField...) separately, and place them in the same DropBox folder, and then put them all back together? What do you suggest? Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you will have to save the data separately...how else would your program know how to create the view?  I recommend JSON or XML.  Don't ask about how to structure it, that is a different question and one you should think about yourself.